# Force bash to wrap output at whitespace

Tags: bash

There are many questions for this actually, but none of them seem to work for my specific needs.

I am using `tmux` and therefore my bash window is pretty small (`$COLUMNS = 45`). This means that pretty much any output is going to get wrapped at its maximum width, which can look pretty gross because long words are getting wrapped in the middle.

While many solutions (e.g. `fold -w 30 -s $FILE`) works fine with files, I can't seem to pipe output from running a program like `python` or `nodejs`. For readability's sake, I'd like to have their outputs wrapped at whitespace.

So for example, when I intentionally generate an error with `nodejs asdgasgsdg` by passing a non-existent file, I want the output to be:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/User/
Documents/cwd/asdgasdg'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (
module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:
25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442
:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Instead of:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/User/Docume
nts/cwd/asdgasdg'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (modu
le.js:326:15)
...
```

I'd like a simple command that can force this kind of wrapping. I was thinking about something like `nodejs non-existent-file.js | fold -w 45`, which doesn't work.

I've also tried piping the output to a file then opening the file with `fold`, but I couldn't get `nodejs` to pipe its error message to `output.txt`. I don't want to manually force the script to log to a file but instead force the *terminal* to do the job. (i.e. I want a working equivalent of `nodejs non-existent-file.js > output.txt; fold -w 45 -s output.txt`. When I tried it, `output.txt` was empty.)

Is this possible?

Comment: try `nodejs non-existent-file.js 2> output.txt; fold -w 45 -s output.txt` and also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/047 on how to redirect stderr to pipe

Answer (score 4):

Piping through `fold` does work with any program that doesn't require its output to be a terminal. And if the program requires its output to be a terminal, it's likely because it does its own formatting.

`nodejs non-existent-file.js | fold -w 45` “doesn't work” because you aren't piping all the output into `fold`, only the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (i.e. application data). You need to join standard output with [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) into the pipe:

```
nodejs non-existent-file.js 2>&1 | fold -w 45
```

But there's an additional wrinkle. Data that is written to a pipe is normally [bufferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) whereas data is not buffered by default when writing to a terminal. Since the pipe is outputting to a terminal, you should disable buffering. With GNU utilities, you can use [stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html).

Also, piping destroys the information of the command's return status. In bash, you can use [`PIPESTATUS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PIPESTATUS) to recover the status of the command; zsh has `pipestatus` to the same effect. Alternatively, in ksh93, bash or zsh, you can use a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution); however bash doesn't wait for the command in the process substitution to finish, which is also a problem.

Furthermore you should only do this wrapping if the output is a terminal. Wrapping logs in files would be very annoying since it destroys a lot of information (you can't rely on line breaks anymore).

```
#!/bin/bash
run_with_word_wrap () {
  if [ -t 1 ]; then
    stdbuf -oL -eL "$@" 2>&1 | fold -w "$COLUMNS"
    return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}

run_with_word_wrap nodejs non-existent-file.js
```